# F# Deedle returns strange output of <fun:it@156-43>

Tags: f#, deedle, fslab

I am getting a strange output from Deedle when I use FirstKey and LastKey on a Frame of Rows.  cl is a DataFrame in the below examples.

```
cl.Rows.FirstKey
```

returns: val it : (unit -> DateTime) = `<fun:it@156-43>` in the FSI window.

```
cl.Rows.LastKey
```

returns: val it : (unit -> DateTime) = `<fun:it@157-44>` in the FSI window.

I am expecting a Key Value of DateTime.  Does anyone recognize the output?  Do I have to do some kind of further processing to get useful output?

Update.  I edited the question so that the complete output from the FSI window is now visible.

Comment: it is returning a function - just call it with `cl.Rows.FirstKey()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by John Palmer has resolved my question.  The correct way to code the FirstKey and LastKey function in my example(s):

```
cl.Rows.FirstKey() 
cl.Rows.LastKey()
```